# Firebase method isn't writing into Firestore DB

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get started with Firebase and am therefore imitating a code example (https://firebase.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web#7) by their site. In this Live-Chat example, I created a function that is supposed to write a message into the Firestore Database. However, no items appear when I open the DB.

```
async function saveMessage(messageText) {
  // TODO 7: Push a new message to Cloud Firestore.
  // Add a new message entry to the Firebase database.
  try {
    console.log(messageText)
    await addDoc(collection(getFirestore(), 'messages'), {
      name: getUserName(),
      text: messageText,
      profilePicUrl: getProfilePicUrl(),
      timestamp: serverTimestamp()
    });
  }
  catch(error) {
    console.error('Error writing new message to Firebase Database', error);
  }
}
```

Other functions:

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import {
  getAuth,
  onAuthStateChanged,
  GoogleAuthProvider,
  signInWithPopup,
  signOut,
} from 'firebase/auth';
import {
  getFirestore,
  collection,
  addDoc,
  query,
  orderBy,
  limit,
  onSnapshot,
  setDoc,
  updateDoc,
  doc,
  serverTimestamp,
} from 'firebase/firestore';
import {
  getStorage,
  ref,
  uploadBytesResumable,
  getDownloadURL,
} from 'firebase/storage';
import { getMessaging, getToken, onMessage } from 'firebase/messaging';
import { getPerformance } from 'firebase/performance';

import { getFirebaseConfig } from './firebase-config.js';
// Signs-in Friendly Chat.
async function signIn() {
  // alert('TODO: Implement Google Sign-In');
  // TODO 1: Sign in Firebase with credential from the Google user.
  // Sign in Firebase using popup auth and Google as the identity provider.
  var provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
  await signInWithPopup(getAuth(), provider);
}

// Signs-out of Friendly Chat.
function signOutUser() {
  // TODO 2: Sign out of Firebase.
  // Sign out of Firebase.
  signOut(getAuth());
}

// Initiate firebase auth
function initFirebaseAuth() {
  // TODO 3: Subscribe to the user's signed-in status
  // Listen to auth state changes.
  onAuthStateChanged(getAuth(), authStateObserver);
}

// Returns the signed-in user's profile Pic URL.
function getProfilePicUrl() {
  // TODO 4: Return the user's profile pic URL.
  return getAuth().currentUser.photoURL
}

// Returns the signed-in user's display name.
function getUserName() {
  // TODO 5: Return the user's display name.
  return getAuth().currentUser.displayName;
}

// Returns true if a user is signed-in.
function isUserSignedIn() {
  // TODO 6: Return true if a user is signed-in.
  return !!getAuth().currentUser;
}

// Saves a new message on the Cloud Firestore.
async function saveMessage(messageText) {
  // TODO 7: Push a new message to Cloud Firestore.
  // Add a new message entry to the Firebase database.
  try {
    console.log(messageText)
    await addDoc(collection(getFirestore(), 'messages'), {
      name: getUserName(),
      text: messageText,
      profilePicUrl: getProfilePicUrl(),
      timestamp: serverTimestamp()
    });
  }
  catch(error) {
    console.error('Error writing new message to Firebase Database', error);
  }
}
```

The server is currently hosted locally with `firebase serve --only hosting`. In my console, neither the try statement log nor the catch error is being printed.

Comment: _"The server is currently hosted locally."_ Are you referring to the Firebase emulators? Also, you do have those `getUserName()` and other functions defined right?

Comment: Yes I did define them, but I hosted it locally with firebase serve --only hosting

Comment: Can you also share how you've initialised Firebase? Are you using Firestore emulator by chance ? or any steps to reproduce the issue

Comment: I added below, I think I am not using Firestone

Comment: Then it should ideally use the production one... I'm not sure if that is complete code but you are never calling `initializeApp()`

Comment: Sorry I forgot but I do initialize. However, my Login for example is working... This should indicate that the project (at least regarding authentication is set up properly). But when it comes to automatically storing the input nothing happens

Comment: was the catch clause executed ? Could you post the error received here?